# Flow Control, If statement looping, else statement not executing

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, control-flow

Within the following code, I can't get past the first `if` statement and proceed to the else `statement`,  even when I purposely make it false:

```
while not scraped:
    print("sleep....")
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        res = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
        links = soup.find_all("span", {"id":"reasonabledoubt"})
        dip = soup.find_all("div")
        print("searching divs")
        if 'keyword' in str(dip) == True:
            print(url)
            print("LINK SCRAPED")
            print(url + " link scraped")
            scraped = True
        else:
            for word in links:
                 print("testing for loop")
                 #rest of code
```

So basically if the keyword isn't found in str(dip), I need the else clause to execute.

Comment: You could reduce this example to one or two lines of code. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood , I was not sure if including the while loop and `try` were relevant to the issue I'm facing, the answer suggested hasn't worked for me...

Comment: The answer should solve it unless you have another issue; I'm assuming you're actually looking for the string `'keyword'` rather than a  variable called `keyword`

Comment: if you get rid of everything except the `if` and `else`, and hard code a value for `dip` you'll be able to test your assumptions. Try it in the interactive console as well, it's a great place to experiment and to clarify your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
if 'keyword' in str(dip):
```

Your old syntax:

```
if 'keyword' in str(dip) == True:
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if 'keyword' in str(dip) and str(dip) == True
```

This is [Python's chaining behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).